# Bind event to dynamically generated form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I have 2 functions, first one calls a form, and second submits that form via ajax. Hovewer I can't bind submit event to newly created form, why is that so ?

Get form

```
$("#discount").click(function(){
 $.ajax({url:"index.php?module=products&view=addajax",success:function(result){
   $(".forma").html(result);
 }});
});
```

Submit this form through ajax

```
$('#my_form').on('submit', (function(evnt){
    evnt.preventDefault(); //Avoid that the event 'submit' continues with its normal execution, so that, we avoid to reload the whole page
    data = $("form#my_form").serialize();
    $.post('index.php/products/adds',
    $("form#my_form").serialize(), //Serialize all the content of our form to URL format
    function (data) {
        $('div#sending_form').prepend(data); //Add the AJAX response to some div that is going to show the message
    }) 
}));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly bind to events of an element that doesn't currently exist. To do that you need to use [delegated events](https://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events)

For example:

```
$('.forma').on('submit', 'form', function(evnt){
    //submit
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `on()` with following syntax:

```
$( "body" ).on( "submit", "#my_form", function() { 
    // your code
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If it has been dynamically added to the page, then you will not be able to bind a click event to it. Instead use `on()` to bind an event to any children newly created from an existing element on the page (that is there when the DOM loads)

Your new on() click event will look something like this:

```
$('.forma').on('click','form', function(e) {
  // logic here
});
```

`.forma` being the class of an element that is present when the DOM is loaded.

Another example:

If you have added `<li>`s to a `<ul>` with jQuery, then you could assign a click event to a hyperlink inside of each `<li>` like so:

```
$('ul.testClass').on('click','li a', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // custom hyperlink behaviour here
});
```

More info about `on()` here: https://api.jquery.com/on/